# android opengl 2.0 live wallpaper lagging

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am developing an OpenGL 2.0 live wallpaper for android and the rendering is laggy (~11fps). In no means am I an expert, but i couldn't find any online resources to answer my question. Benchmarking, I found out that 'onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused)' stalls because of how many objects I use. I get an OK framerate if i restrict it to rendering ~100 objects, but my wallpaper consists of a raster of ~1000 triangles. Is this the problem? Here is the code:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {

    if (para.xOffset > f) {
        Matrix.translateM(mViewMatrix, 0, (para.xOffset - f) * 10, 0, 0);
        f = para.xOffset;
    } else {
        Matrix.translateM(mViewMatrix, 0, (para.xOffset - f) * 10, 0, 0);
        f = para.xOffset;
    }

    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLES20.glUseProgram(mPerVertexProgramHandle);

    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mPerVertexProgramHandle,
            "u_MVPMatrix");
    mMVMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mPerVertexProgramHandle,
            "u_MVMatrix");
    mLightPosHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mPerVertexProgramHandle,
            "u_LightPos");
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mPerVertexProgramHandle,
            "a_Position");
    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mPerVertexProgramHandle,
            "a_Color");
    mNormalHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mPerVertexProgramHandle,
            "a_Normal");

    Matrix.setIdentityM(mLightModelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(mLightModelMatrix, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);
    Matrix.translateM(mLightModelMatrix, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f);

    Matrix.multiplyMV(mLightPosInWorldSpace, 0, mLightModelMatrix, 0,
            mLightPosInModelSpace, 0);

    for (newHexagon nha[] : h.hfgrd) {
        for (newHexagon nh : nha) {

            Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
            Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, nh.PosX, nh.PosY, -5);

            final FloatBuffer colors;
            colors = ByteBuffer
                    .allocateDirect(nh.colors.length * mBytesPerFloat)
                    .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
            colors.put(nh.colors).position(0);

            drawthis(colors);
        }

    }

    GLES20.glUseProgram(mPointProgramHandle);

    h.draw(0, 0);
}
```

**edit:** Additional Information: the triangles are unisize and arranged in a flat hexagonal tiling of the screen.

CPU: Dual-core 1.2 GHz Scorpion

GPU: Adreno 220

Device: HTC Sensation

Android v4.0.3

Comment: What CPU, GPU and Device?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 major problems in your code:

1. Don't call `glGetUniformLocation` on each frame - assign them to fields once after shader compilation. Getting uniforms/attributes is a rather expensive operation.
2. You may generate too much draw calls (`glDrawElements` or `glDrawArrays`). Your `drawthis()` method supposedly issues at least one draw call. It is OK for modern hardware to handle max 200-500 draw calls. Each draw call has a small overhead of driver-to-GPU communication so the best practice is to batch multiple draw calls as much as possible. But please provide code of `drawthis()` for better understanding of problem.
3. `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()` on each draw call. You have to avoid any memory allocations, and you are doing it in loop.